# Why is AC current inversely proportional to voltage?

Tags: voltage, current

[image]

Why is AC current inversely proportional to voltage?

I think that current should be proportional to voltage, because according to \$V=IR\$, when \$R\$ is fixed, the bigger \$I\$ is, the bigger \$V\$ should be. But according to this simulation, the relationship between \$I\$ and  \$V\$ is negative. Is the software the problem? I use Virtuoso Cadence to simulate the circuit.

I have another question. The direction of the arrow should be the direction of the current. Why is the first half wave negative?

Is the meter "flipped around" in 1 (below)? Or, should I modify something in 2? I had tried simulating 1, but it didn’t change the relation between the voltage and current.

[image]

Comment: Tried flipping the meter around?

Comment: @immibis but that shouldn't change the relation between voltage and current

Comment: @XM551 flip either the voltmeter or the ammeter around. One but not both. This is just a polarity or sign convention error. No big deal.

Comment: The direction on the ammeter tells you which way positive current flows. In order to have current and voltage in-phase, you need the positive current to flow into the + side of the resistor. Right now, positive current is flowing the other way. Just flip the ammeter and run it again. You will see. It will be just as you expect.

Comment: @XM551 What do you think it means when an ammeter shows a negative value? It means the current is going backwards through the meter. If you flip it around the current would be going forwards through the meter. Same for voltmeters.

Comment: Because the power is held constant...

Comment: That's not inverse proportionality.  Inverse proportionality is $$I \propto \frac{1}{V}$$.  What you see is $$I \propto -V$$

Comment: I have another question,The direction of arrow should be the direction of current,why the first half wave is negative?

Comment: i had modify my question,now i think the thing i can't understand is the meaning of "flipping the meter around",can you please see my question again?thx

Comment: The tab on your green current plot reads: “/I7/MINUS”. What does “MINUS” indicate?

Comment: i don't know,i am not pretty sure about that

Comment: ...but if I∝−V than also I∝V. Problem solved.

Comment: @Curd NO it's not

Comment: @XM551: What do you mean "it's not"? Isn't I∝−V ? And -1 is a constant, therfore also I∝ (−1) -V, i.e. I∝V

Comment: @Curd I think for positive voltage \$6 \gt  1\$,but for negative voltage \$-6 \lt  -1\$

Comment: @XM551: it's not clear at all what you want to say. Of course 6>1 and -6<-1. So what?!?!

Comment: if a ∝ b,that means the bigger a is ,the bigger b is.so if I ∝ -V,it should mean wean i=1 ,-V=-2,then i=2,-V=-1.BUT,I ∝ V should be like i=1 ,V=2,then i=2,V=3.As you said if I∝−V than also I∝V,then it will become  i=1 ,-V=-2,then i=2,-V=-1;i=2,V=1,but we know 1<3.i hope you can know what i explain

Comment: @XM551: No *proportional* means that both variables have a fixed (constant) ratio; even if the ratio is negative; What you should have written in your question is  "Why has current the opposite sign as expected?". I **is** proportional to V, even if the sign is "the wrong way".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cadence has a convention to use the current flowing out of the device as negative. You are measuring the current at the positive node of the current source so the current is negative. Measure it at the node connected to resistor, you will get positive current.

Answer (score 1):

A flipped Ammeter while simulation - Probably what is happening in there.

[image]

[Link to the simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0Av%2064%20272%2064%20368%200%201%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%2064%20272%20160%20272%200%203000%0Aw%2064%20368%20224%20368%200%0Aw%20224%20272%20224%20368%200%0Aw%20464%20272%20464%20368%200%0Aw%20304%20368%20464%20368%200%0A370%20464%20272%20400%20272%201%200%0Ar%20304%20272%20400%20272%200%203000%0Av%20304%20272%20304%20368%200%201%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0A370%20160%20272%20224%20272%201%200%0Ao%200%2064%200%204098%205%200.00625%200%202%200%203%0Ao%209%2064%200%204097%205%200.003125%200%202%209%203%0Ao%208%2064%200%204098%205%200.0125%201%202%208%203%0Ao%206%2064%200%204097%200.0000762939453125%200.003125%201%202%206%203%0A)

Comment: Are you simulate the same point?

Comment: Same ckt. Same measuring points.

Comment: I had modify my question,now i think the thing i can't understand is  the meaning of "flipping the meter around",can you please see my question again?thx

Comment: What is "V" in your graph ? Which point is your probe at ? Left or right side of Resistor ?

Comment: V is the voltage on the red line,the point is the green circle.you can see it from the first picture

Answer (score 0):

I think you are the confusing the word “meter” with your current source. They are two different things.

Changing the direction of your current source won’t fix your problem, if the direction of the measurement changes with it.

Is your plot measuring the flow of electrons or (conventionally) holes? When you add the current plot to your simulation, your CAD is likely adding it in a fix, albeit backwards, direction.

Comment: How do i know my plot is measuring the flow of electrons or (conventionally) holes?

Comment: It is measuring conventional current. How do you know this? Because nobody every measures electrons. Ever. It is always conventional current. Just forget about electrons unless you are studying device physics or chemistry.

Comment: @mkeith I agree, and just threw it out there to be sure. The only reason I considered it is this: my son has a class in electronics (middle school) and came to me for help earlier this week. I was surprised to learn that the students were all being taught their circuit analysis in electron-flow current! I was appalled, and seriously considered scheduling an appointment to talk to his teacher.

Comment: Wow, @BlairFonville, I too am appalled and surprised!

Comment: @mkeith I was actually quite frustrated about it; especially so because I know he took the class to make me proud, and so I hide my disappointment. I really should talk to the teacher.